# Is there any way to possibly find intersection of Polygons in Leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, polygon

For example, If I have two polygons that are getting intersected at some point in Leaflet. Is there any way to find the intersection of polygons? Please suggest me regarding this. I am using Flask application and creating web application where I need to find out these points.

Comment: the turf library has a lot of functions, also intersection. https://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect . I don't know if there is a version for python

Comment: Is there any possibility to add Turf library in python web application ?

Comment: Have you saw this google entry? https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2017/lessons/L3/point-in-polygon.html

Comment: @FalkeDesign: This sounds intresting...thank you. I will look into it